# Cannot Dismiss Modal View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm having a problem getting my modal view controller to properly display and then dismiss. Basically I have a modally displayed login window and I want to dismiss it after all the data that I want to display is loaded from the database. if I call

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` from within the LoginViewController class it works perfectly fine but if I call

`[[mainController modalViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` from within my datamanager class after I have successfully imported the data nothing happens. Which is extremely confusing because `[mainController modalViewController]` points to the locationManager class.

Does anybody have any ideas as to why this isn't working? I'm programming for iOS 4 if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using: [_splitViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES]; in applicationDIdFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK So I figured this out. Basically what was happening was that the [self dismissModalViewController] call was happening on another thread which for whatever reason means that the object did not properly process the dismiss message. I ended up using a notification and then called dismissModalView controller like so:

```
- (void)dismissSelf
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}

- (void)receiveDismissNotification:(NSNotification *) note
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dismissSelf) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

which works

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to dismiss a modal view controller is to call `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` on the view controller that presented it. Thus it should be `[_splitViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

From your comment, you need to call `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` on the main thread, you can do this like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_splitViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
});
```

Comment: I tried that with: [mainController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] and it does not work...

Comment: I'm setting mainController in application did finish launching with options with: [[DataStore defaultStore] setMainController:_splitViewController];

Comment: Not true. The proper way to dismiss a modal view controller is to call that method on the modal view controller itself.

Comment: in the docs it says that dismissModalViewController dismisses the modal view controller that was presented by the receiver. But that is confusing because the observed behaviour differs from that (i.e. what hypercrypt said usually works). Maybe it changed in iOS 5 or something?

Comment: @FreaknBigPanda the docs also say `If you call this method on the modal view controller itself, however, the modal view controller automatically forwards the message to its parent view controller`

Comment: @Steve Exactly, you are supposed to call it on the view controller that presents it, (i.e. `[a presentModalViewController:b animated:YES]; ... [a dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. Most of the time `[b dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` will be fine, but if you have also called `[b presentModalViewController:c animated:YES];` then `[b dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` will dismiss `c` rather than `b` and `c`. If you want to dismiss both you should call `[a dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` as the documentation and my answer say.

Comment: @hypercrypt - Understood - however, there is a reason you'll rarely, if ever, see someone (including Apple) do that in sample code - because it limits the reusability of that modal dialog. Unless you're doing `[modalViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` which can be simplified to `[modalViewController dismiss...]`. It's just bad OOP to do it any other way. Now, I understand if that makes you mad, and feel like you need to go downvote all my other answers/questions (Which you have been), but, oh well, that's my opinion.

Comment: I haven't and I don't care, I do it all the time myself. I wish that `[b dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` did always dismiss `b` and any child view controllers, but the method in my answer is, sadly, the correct one.

Comment: So I have been thinking about this and the call to dismiss the modalViewController takes place on another thread. Could this be causing my problem?

Comment: Yes, all calls to UIKit need to happen on the main thread - updated answer.

Comment: This worked for me. Looks like the reason is because my call to dismiss was run in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

To close the Model View Controller use following code

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This code works with ios 5 also.

For presenting the model view controller

```
if (self.viewController!=nil)
{
       //sanity check for view controller
       [self.viewController SOMEVIEW animated:YES];
}
```